# Compilation from source: Cannot read contents from file on static -content deploy for uber craft theme in magento2

Tags: php, deployment, themes, static-content, magento-2.0

i have installed magento2 and try to configure uber craft theme,
but when i try to run the magneto command to deploy static content. it shows error for new theme while default theme it shows no error. Error is as below.

```
=== frontend -> UberTheme/craft -> en_US ===
...............................................................
...............................................................
...............................................................
...............................................................
...............................................................
...............................................................
...............................................................
...........................................
Compilation from source:
frontend/UberTheme/craft/en_US/css/styles-l.less
Cannot read contents from file "C:/xampp/htdocs/Magento/" >
```

i am executing below command

C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento>php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and in my case was an empty CSS file in `app > design > frontend > VerndorName > ThemeName > web > css`. Make sure you don't have any empty files.

Comment: Is this not considered a bug in the core? Is there an issue being tracked on GitHub about it?